# Asp.net MVC sql only on repository layer

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Good mornig, i have an asp.net mvc application (in particular asp.net webapi).

layers structure:

1. Asp.net MVC | console application
2. data access 1 | data access 2
3. database 1 | database 2

I need to create a data access layer on a separate project (class library) to be used from other projects in the same solution. Can i specify the connection string and data configurations only on that class? Because i have to specify the connection and data library references on every parent layer.

i want only the data access layer (class library) to be referenced to system.data classes and to have specified connection strings. I want this because of comlexity of my structure and to have different data access libraries to access different data sources without ever changing asp.net mvc configuration.

Comment: If you include the connection information directly in the code (not recommended), you could certainly specify only for that class. However if your application draws from the ConnectionStrings section of your app/web.config file, then it will take the setting from the current running assembly location and therefor would need to be specified in the appropriate .config file.

Comment: my problem is that i have multiple data sources (sqlserver, mysql and go on) and i must read them from a lot of frontend applications (console, winformms, web application). i would like to avoid referencing mysql and sqlserver assembly from the asp.net mvc or other front applications

Comment: I would just use a different connectionStrings entry for each case and then distribute only what you would need with each application scope.

Unused settings in the app/web.config will simply be disregarded if they are not used - they shouldn't have anything to do with requiring dependencies - they are basically just name/value pairs just like an AppSettings entry.

Comment: the real problem is not connection strung but is the library reference

Comment: I think I perhaps Iam misunderstanding your dilemma. 

Is the real problem that you don't want to introduce, for example, as MySQL dependency into your Asp.Net MVC application, but it should be included in your console application?

You should probably use some type of inversion of control to allow you to keep out those dependencies as compile time. I don't think having or not having a connection string somewhere will get you anywhere.

Comment: i'd like to create a class library that is  independent, so the external applications should only use the "public" interface, i want to create a "package"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement and IProvider interface that is all your application (Asp.Net MVC or Console app) is aware of. In a separate library, implment MySQLProvider, MyMongoDBProvider, and MySQLProvider.

Use TinyIOC in your applications to handle inversion of control (there are lots of other options, but that is the first one I could think of that would search your bin directory automatically for an implementation) and then package each application with the appropriate provider implementation.